# Excel 2016 - If a cell equals 1, then output new number

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I have an output (Column AL) which either equals 1 (option wanted) or 0 (option not wanted) on column AM, there are many options which I want to identify with unique numbers 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 etc (Column AN)

```
AL      -       AM      -      AN
'option 1'      -        1      -       1
'option 2'      -       0      -       0
'option 3'      -        0      -       0 
'option 4'      -        1          -   2
'option 5'      -        1         -    3
'option 6'      -        1       -      4
'option 7'      -        1      -       5
'option 8'      -        0       -      0
'option 9'     -         0       -      0
'option 10'     -        0       -      0
'option 11'      -       0      -       0
'option 12'     -        0      -       0
'option 13'     -        1      -       6
'option 14'       -      0       -      0 
'option 15'      -       0       -      0
'option 16'     -        1       -      7
etc
```

I've been trying to sort this for the last couple of days but don't seem to be able to grasp it using 'IFs' - any one have a (probably simple) solution........

(note i don't want to do this with a macro)

Comment: Not at all clear what you are trying to achieve. Perhaps just a simple `=IF(AM17=1;SUM(AM2:AM17);0)` in AN17 would do?

Comment: I have an option page which selects the option output number linked to these results - ive used the sum formula below by Mate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be plenty of solutions for this problem, find two of them below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Mate, yes ive used the sum version and it works a treat!!